# Running for loop to sum elements of different dictionary

Tags: python

I want to add similar key values present in a large number of dictionary. I am running a for loop over all the dictionary and updating the keys values but instead of summing the keys values it is giving that value of key which is present in last dictionary. 
For example: If x,y,z are 3 dictionary, I want to add similar element values present in all the dictionary using for loop as number of dictionary can be large in number.

```
x = {'both1':0, 'both2':2, 'only_x': 100 }
y = {'both1':1, 'both2': -200, 'only_y':203 }
z = {'both1':5, 'both2': 400, 'only_y':13 }

a = {}
for i in x,y,z:
    a.update(i)
print a
```

Output:

```
{'only_y': 13, 'both2': 400, 'only_x': 100, 'both1': 5}
```

Expected Output:

```
{'only_y': 216, 'both2': 202, 'only_x': 100, 'both1': 6}
```

Comment: @BcK No, I don't think that dupe applies, OP wants values to be added for keys.

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to use Counter:

```
a = {}
for i in [x,y,z]:
    for k,v in i.iteritems():
        if k in a.keys():
            a[k] = a[k] + v
        else:
            a[k] = v
```

Note that you need to use a.items() instead of a.iteritems() if you are using python 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get rid of `if .. else ...`:

```
a = {}
for i in x,y,z:
    for k, v in i.iteritems():
        a[k] = a.get(k, 0) + v
```

Comment: In response to your comment: they _do_ work with negative values, they just don't work here for some reason. However, summing explicitly gives you the right answer: `Counter({'both1':1, 'both2': -200, 'only_y':203 }) + Counter( {'both1':5, 'both2': 400, 'only_y':13 }) + Counter({'both1':0, 'both2':2,'only_x': 100 })`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Counter` in this case, *but* in order to handle the negative values you should use the `update` method.

From documentation:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.update

> ... and decimals would work and negative values are supported. The same is also true for update() and subtract() which allow negative and zero values for both inputs and outputs.

---

```
from collections import Counter

x = {'both1': 0, 'both2': 2, 'only_x': 100}
y = {'both1': 1, 'both2': -200, 'only_y': 203}
z = {'both1': 5, 'both2': 400, 'only_y': 13}

C = Counter(x)
C.update(y)
C.update(z)

# {'only_y': 216, 'both2': 202, 'only_x': 100, 'both1': 6}
```

You can automate this by defining a function,

```
def updateCounter(*args):
    C = Counter()

    for arg in args:
        C.update(arg)
    return C

updateCounter(x, y, z)

# output 
# Counter({'only_y': 216, 'both2': 202, 'only_x': 100, 'both1': 6})
```